# gspread Python Форматирование типа ячеек

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet, gspread

Можете подсказать, как через `gspread` корректно выполнить форматирование ячейки, чтобы она приняла тип `Дата\Время`?

[Линк на документацию API GooglSheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells?hl=ru#numberformattype)

Моя задача избавиться от апострафа при добавлении даты в ячейку. Все данные прилетают в виде строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При коде ниже вызывает ошибку, что "type" неизвестный параметр

```
worksheet.format('H2:H1000', {"type": enum(DATE_TIME)})
```

Comment: `worksheet.format('H2:H1000', { "numberFormat": { "type": "DATE_TIME" }})`?

Comment: Спасибо. Проходит без ошибки, но проблему с апострофом не решает :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62145985/date-time-output-has-single-quote-in-front-of-variable-in-google-sheet?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Решения реализации через код не нашел. Гугл таблица все равно считывала как текст, а не как дату в ячейке.
Решением было создать еще одну таблицу в файле которая ссылается на выгруженые данные и преобразовав данные через функцию =DATE_VATUE()

Answer (score 0):

Вашу проблему может решить добавление `value_input_option='USER_ENTERED'` во время отправки значений в таблицу. Гугл будет вводить значения как введенные человеком -
строковые значения чисел и дат автоматически изменят формат ячеек.
`sheet.worksheet('name').update([output_df.columns.values.tolist()] + output_df.values.tolist() , value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')`